# Limit of the sum of functions and limit of the product of a function and a constant

Tags: real-analysis, limits

These are the questions :

[image]

I have a big feeling c is false but I can't find any counter example, the same for d.

Comment: Hint: for (d), how might the algebraic limit theorem help you here?

Comment: For Part C, write $g=(f+g)-f$.  Then, $\lim g=\lim (f+g)-\lim (f)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C) I am assuming that you are considering a limit of infinity to be a valid limit. Let $x_o = o$ and $f(x)=1/x^2$ which has a limit of infinity. Let $g(x)$ be 1 for $x>0$ and 0 for $x\le0$.

D) If we assume c is not 0 then if we consider a sequence coming from the left and the right of $x_o$, we can divide each term by c and have a new sequence converging to the limit of $c*f(x)/c$.